# How to pass selected query list using ViewBag

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have Fetched data from sql server and pass it to a list as mentioned below

```
var query = (from employee in db.LKEmployeeDatas   //Getting data from databse from join without using foreign key relationship
             join transaction in db.AssetTransactions on employee.SamAccountName equals transaction.SamAccountName
             select new 
             {
                displayName=employee.SamAccountName                     
             }).ToList();
```

And I added and passed above list to view using ViewBag

```
ViewBag.query = query;
```

after that I display that list as mentioned bellow

```
@{    
    foreach (var k in ViewBag.query)
    {
       @k.displayName
    }
}
```

But it gives me the following error

> Exception Details:
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does
>   not contain a definition for 'displayName'

I can't understand what the solution is

Comment: It say's it all in your exception `object does not contain a definition for displayName`.

Comment: Recommend using `ViewModels` as it's much easier to work with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer by Matěj is correct in the context of your question. Just to add to that though, if you wanted to pass a more complex object list to your `View` you could do one of these...I'm assuming you have a class/model called `Employee` which mimics some/all of the columns in your `Employee` table for these examples:

**Option 1:**

In the controller:

```
List<Employee> query = (from employee in db.LKEmployeeDatas   //Getting data from databse from join without using foreign key relationship
                 join transaction in db.AssetTransactions on employee.SamAccountName equals transaction.SamAccountName
                 select new Employee()
                 {
                     displayName=employee.SamAccountName,
                     otherField=employee.otherField
                 }).ToList();

ViewBag.LKEmployeeDatasList = query;
```

In the View:

```
@{
    var myList = ViewBag.LKEmployeeDatasList==null ? new List<LKEmployeeDatas>() : (List<LKEmployeeDatas>)ViewBag.LKEmployeeDatasList;

    if(myList.Any()) {
       foreach(var item in myList) {
           @item.displayName
           @item.otherField
       }
    }
}
```

The `if(myList.Any())` will protect you against any errors resulting from no ViewBag being present...as does the iif statement on the ViewBag preceeding this.

**Option 2:**

Make the view strongly-typed.

In the controller:

```
List<Employee> query = (from employee in db.LKEmployeeDatas   //Getting data from databse from join without using foreign key relationship
                     join transaction in db.AssetTransactions on employee.SamAccountName equals transaction.SamAccountName
                     select new Employee()
                     {
                         displayName=employee.SamAccountName,
                         otherField=employee.otherField
                     }).ToList();

 return View(query);  //passing a List<Employee> object over to the view
```

In the View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Employee>
@if(Model.Any()) {
    foreach(var item in myList) {
        @item.displayName
        @item.otherField
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ViewBag is a dynamic object - you can store whatever in it, when retrieving items from it you have to cast them to their correct (eg. original) types.

```
 foreach (var k in (originalTypeOfQuery)ViewBag.query)
 {
   @k.displayName
 }
```

Looking at your code, maybe it would be best to cast output of your query to a `List<string>`, since you are only retrieving `SamAccountName` property of `employee`. In case you'd need to get more properties, create a class mapping these properties.

Comment: I  am getting following compilation error  ``foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'originalTypeOfQuery' because 'originalTypeOfQuery' does not contain public instance definition for getenumerator``

Comment: Hover cursor over "var" in your original code at point var query = (from...
now assuming you are using VS strongly typed result of your function should pop over the var. Replace "originalTypeOfQuery" with it.

Comment: @RasinduDeAlwis you can accept and upvote my answer if it helped you, thanks